Linear Regression R-Squared Adjusted
i have some problems with formulas.
The first formula that i found in the internet

The second formula

I calculate R-Squared Adjusted through stats.model in Python and thats it equal 0.610408.
R-Squared ≈ 0.6415759298804311
n = 51
k = 4
First formula result = 1 - (1 - 0.64157) * (50 / 47) ≈ 0.61869
Second formula result = 1 - (1 - 0.64157) * (50 / 46) ≈ 0.610408
Why is the first formula that is on the internet incorrect?

You should probably ask this in https://math.stackexchange.com/ instead

What does k mean in the two formulas? I guarantee the only difference is in how these are defined.

As Noah pointed out. There are two common definitions across the literature, k with or without the constant, that is k is the number of slope variables or k is the number of columns in the design matrix.

The first formula uses (n-1)/(n-k) as the adjustment factor. This does not correctly account for degree of freedom in the denominator, which should be adjusted for both intercept and predictor.  The second formular (n-1)/(n-(n+k)) correctly accounts for the degree of freedom, hence gives a more accurate estimate of R-squared.
The second formular aligns with the calculations performed by statsmodels, and other statistical software. This explains why it aligns with your answer.
